# Rails create method not adding record to the table, but works for the IRB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've looked everywhere for a similar error but couldn't find a solution, so in desperation I'm posting here.

My controller has this:

```
def add_upc
        @upcs = Dvd.add_upc(params[:dogTag], params[:newUpc])
    end
```

and in the Model we have:

```
def self.add_upc(dogTag, newUpc)
    existingUpc = Dvd.find(dogTag).dvd_upc2title.find_by_upc(newUpc)
    if existingUpc.nil? 
        createdUpc = Dvd.find(dogTag).dvd_upc2title.create(:upc => newUpc)
        if createdUpc
            upcs = createdUpc
        else
            upcs = 'Error: nothing was created'
        end
    end
end
```

I've set up a view page to see what's happening and I can see the object being created by createdUpc. I can also confirm that the parameters dogTag and newUpc are being passed correctly. Yet the record is not being added to the table.

Weirdly, this does work if I issue the `Dvd.find(dogTag).dvd_upc2title.create(:upc => newUpc)` command with the values substituted for the variables from the IRB.

Can't figure out why this is not working. I'm new to Rails so don't know what other error debugging I could use to figure out where the problem lies.

Ideas are welcome.

Thanks.

Edit:

Found the error thanks to RyanWilcox, it was the validation I had set up in the controller for UPC telling me that value already existed (even though UPCs are supposed to be unique. Is there a way to validate on a combination of 2 fields?

Comment: have a look at your log/development.log and try executing Dvd.add_upc with those parameters. there might be some naming issue or the like. so try putting out all the params that you use in your method.

Comment: @phoet this does give me a clue. The log doesn't show anything when I run Dvd.add_upc from the IRB, but it does return `:newUpc` which is not what I expected at all. Am I passing the parameters from the controller above correctly? What could the `:newUpc` symbol mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I really like doing for situations like this ("why did this fail to save?") is using `create!` instead of `create`.

This will throw an exception on error, with the failed validation's text as the message of the exception. It makes problems like this obvious.

Comment: Ah, fantastic! Didn't know about this. Using `create!` produces this error: `Validation failed: Upc has already been taken`. But I'm not sure what this means. Upc (capital) seems to be referring to the model maybe? Those values don't exist in the table, so it's not that.

Comment: Found it, it was the validation I had set up in the controller for UPC telling me that value already existed. Is there a way to validate on a combination of 2 fields?

Comment: That's a good question, and I don't know the answer off the top of my head. My suggestion is to do some googling or open another SO question. (it's probably a "possible, but non-obvious" answer).